# Find text in Word using Range finds text beyond the text selected

Tags: vba, find, ms-word

I am trying to find numbers at the start of a paragraph where the operator has selected the paragraphs to be searched.
For some reason the search finds the number (text) at the start of the next paragraph, even if the selection ends half-way through the first paragraph.

```
Set oRng = Application.Selection.Range
Set sText = Application.Selection
MsgBox sText
Debug.Print Application.Selection.Paragraphs.count
Debug.Print oRng.start & " " & oRng.End
Debug.Print "-------------------------------------"
With oRng.Find
    .Text = "^13[0-9A-Da-d]{1,10}"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    Do While oRng.InRange(Selection.Range)
        Debug.Print Selection.Range.start & " " & Selection.Range.End
        Debug.Print oRng.start & " " & oRng.End
        If .Execute Then
            Debug.Print Selection.Range.start & " " & Selection.Range.End
            Debug.Print oRng.start & " " & oRng.End
            Debug.Print oRng.Text
            Set xRng = Application.ActiveDocument.Range(start:=oRng.start + 1, End:=oRng.start + 12)
            'getRefs.Add Mid(oRng.Text, 2)
            getRefs.Add xRng.Text
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End With
```

The output I get is as follows :-
 2

### 1389 1753

1389 1753
1389 1753
1389 1753
1399 1401

1
1389 1753
1401 1401
1389 1753
1754 1756

2

The first 2 is the number of paragraphs, the first of which does not begin with a number.
Then the start and end of the selection.
The entry 1754 1756 is the range of the text at the start of the third paragraph which from the above is clearly not in the initial selection.

The paragraphs might look like this :-
Title
1. Text here sd
2. More text here
(Except the paragraphs are longer than just a few words.)
I am using xRng to get text including the found text (less paragraph marker) and some following text.

Comment: Not sure why R3uK destroyed the immediate window output I provided and reformatted the numbers as above, it doesn't make sense as currently displayed.

Comment: Jim, is the information now displayed the way you intended? (Because it's still not making a lot of sense). FWIW I wouldn't use InRange(Selection.Range), I'd create a second Range object and do dupRange = oRng.Duplicate. Word Ranges are odd beasts - if you do Set dupRange = oRng any changes you make to the one are reflected in the other, so you have to use Duplicate. And you should't rely on Selection as that could change. Also note this makes no sense: Set sText = Application.Selection as Selection returns a RANGE object. Should be: sText = Selection.Text if you want the text.